# Quick reply needed - How to disable / Inactive the production version in Play Store?

Tags: google-play, version, production, beta, disable

How to inactive current production version in Google Play store, current Production (v15) and Beta to unlimited user(v18).
How to inactivate the production version and keep the beta version active. Is there any solution to disable the specific version?
Hope someone have experienced this issue and found solution.

Please share your solution.